# The center div is not adjusting when the div inside with float attribute is adjusting

Tags: css, html, height, center

I'm working with divs and I managed to make the wrapper center by having this css:

```
.wrapper{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
width:1100px;
height:100%;
}
```

then I have this  inside that is floated left. It went inside but my problem is when it gets longer, it pass the wrapper div. The wrapper div should also adjust when the height of the div inside adjust but it's not working. When I also float the wrapper, it also adjusts but it doesn't go to the center anymore.

```
.inside_div{
float:left;
margin:5px;
width:400px;
height:100%;
}
```

What I tried to do is to float the wrapper div and use:

```
margin-left:200px;
```

to adjust it and to make it look that it's in the center. But I based it on my laptop's screen. It may not be centered on different screens with different sizes.

What I wanted to see is that the wrapper div will be centered in all screens and it will also adjust when the div inside adjusts too. I just don't know how to do it.I tried dfferent ways but still same result.

This is the html part:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
   <div class="logo">
   </div>
   <div class="menu">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="inside_div">
   </div>
   <div class="inside_div2">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="footer">
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

The inside_div2 is floated right.

Comment: If the provided answer doesn't provide a solution, please provide more than your `CSS`... as in `HTML`.

Comment: You might want to try adding padding to the outside div, and removing the margin from the inside div.

Comment: I mean, the HTML is probably a div within a div.

Comment: @QuentinEngles is right, remove the 5px margin you've set on the inner div and replace it with 'margin: 0 auto;' and remove the 'float:left;' if you don't want it to stick to the left.

Comment: I just want the wrapper div to be on center. And the inside div to float left. I already managed that but the problem is that the wrapper div is not adjusting when the inside_div's height is adjusting.

Comment: How are you adjusting the inside div? Are you adjusting it independently?

Comment: Yes. I'm putting texts and divs inside that <inside_div>.. and what I have been doing all this time is to make the height of the parent div/inside_div to be 100% or auto so it will adjust automatically when the height of the divs inside it or he texts inside it adjusts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all height properties and add a "clearfix" class to your wrapper.

In your css, define ".clearfix" as :

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

That should do the trick for modern browsers. You should definitely Google "clearfix" to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Floated objects won't expand their parents. Your initial css height value is all that the parent container has to reference for its height. By the way, height:100% is generally not going to work for you and is rarely something you should include.

Without seeing exactly what you're trying to do, this would probably work fine. Although it depends a bit what you have inside the 'inside_div':

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
  text-align: left;
}

.inside_div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

I assume you wanted it off to the left since you were floating it left. But if you just want it centered, you can either just remove your float value and use margin: 0 auto; or use the css above and change text-align to center.

EDIT: Ok, so had to recheck your stuff above. I think what you want is simply this:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inside_div {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That'll center both of them, regardless of the size of the screen. You can add a height value to the inside_div if you need, but px values would be best, and if you have content in there is usually best just to let the content dictate the height without explicitly setting it.

Comment: but if I use margin:o auto; also in the inside_div, it will adjust to the center.

Comment: If you wanted the inner container off to the left after all, the first solution will do that while allowing the parent to resize for more content.